# Changing navigation Left Bar button title while selecting collection cell inside a container view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uicontainerview

I have a collection view inside a container view. In collection view I have two parts as, `UICollectionReusableView` and `UICollectionViewCell` . Inside the UICollectionReusableView again I have a collection view and while selecting a cell from that cell I have to change the `LeftNavigationBarTitle`. I tried the below code in didSelectItem of collection view but nothing is happen.

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "cancel-music")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.closeViewTapped)).
```

I used the above code but it didn't change the navigationButton.

[image]

This my storyBoard design.
Is any mistake in my code, please help me to get the exact one. Thankyou.

Comment: What do you want to change the navigation bar title or Left Bar button title?

Comment: left bar button title

Comment: What is name of `UIViewController` which contains collection view?

Comment: @MayurKarmur HomeFilterVC

Comment: @AngelFSyrus, Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the protocol method for view controller which contains collection view.

Inside `HomeFilterVC`

```
protocol HomeFilterVCDelegate: class {
    func collectionViewDidTapped()
}
```

Then, declare delegate variable like as follow, which will assign to your view controller which contains `UIContainerView`.

```
class HomeFilterVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate                   : HomeFilterVCDelegate?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let selfDelegate = self.delegate {
            selfDelegate.collectionViewDidTapped()
        }
    }
}
```

Implement `prepare(for segue:, sender:)` and `HomeFilterVCDelegate` methods in `HomeVC` and update your code as follow.

**HomeVC:**

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "HomeFilterVC" {

            let collectionVC = segue.destination as! HomeFilterVC
            collectionVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

extension HomeVC: HomeFilterVCDelegate {

    func collectionViewDidTapped() {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "cancel-music")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.closeViewTapped)).
    }
}
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: showing error as **Use of unresolved identifier 'selfDelegate** in HomeFilterVC and also I am not using segue here.

Comment: Sry it's typo mistake, use as `if let selfDelegate = self.delegate { }`

Comment: In extension of HomeVC showing **Use of undeclared type 'CollectionVCDelegate'** and how do I connect delegate to HomeFilterVC

Comment: Actually, you are using container view which are embedding view controller, so set `HomeFilterVC` identifier there, so you can fix your issues.

Comment: Just update it to `HomeFilterVCDelegate` instead of `CollectionVCDelegate`, Actually I have changed protocol name based on your class name.

Comment: Check this image, click on it and set identifier from attribute inspector: https://imgur.com/vfDrXUC

Comment: @AngelFSyrus, Check this demo app: https://gofile.io/?c=addXk5. Only check `VC1` & `MainVC`, let me know still you need any help.

Comment: Wait I will check and update you. Thank you so much for taking effort for helping me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Woww its It worked like a charm! .Thank you so much

Comment: @AngelFSyrus, Happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change button title like below :

```
func changeBarButtonTitle() {
    let leftitem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!
    let leftbutton = leftitem.customView as! UIButton
    leftbutton.setTitle("<YOUR-TITLE>", for: .normal)
}
```

Also if you know that a button already there and just want to change title use below function.

```
func changeBarButtonTitle() {

        if let leftitem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem {
            print("Left Button")
            leftitem.title = "test-left"
        }

        if let rightitem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem {
            print("Right Button")
            rightitem.title = "test-right"
        }
    }
```

Hope this will helps to change bar button title!

Comment: your app is navigation base app right or single view controler app ?

Comment: Navigation base app

Comment: You have already leftbarbutton in your navigation bar right? and just want to update the title of that bar button?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a `property` for `leftItem` in your `ViewController` that will save the `reference` to `leftBarButtonItem` i.e.

```
class VC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    lazy var leftItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Initial Title")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(closeViewTapped))
        return item
    }()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.leftItem
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've added the `leftBarButtonItem` initially in  `viewWillAppear(_:)`. Since we're saving the `reference` to `leftBarButtonItem` in `leftItem`, we can make any changes to it using `leftItem`.

Then in your `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` use the same `property` to change your `leftBarButtonItem's title`, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.leftItem.title = "Title at Index - \(indexPath.row)"
}
```